# Geckoview on Android

Tags: android, webview, geckoview

I'm trying to get Geckoview setup in my android app. I am following the tutorial [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/consumer/geckoview-quick-start.html) but I get an error that it doesn't exist. Is anyone familar with Geckoview who can help me out? Did it move or something?

Here is the error I get

> Could not find
> org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-nightly:97.0.20211210143634. Required
> by:
> project :app

Ive followed the instructions and have

```
    implementation "org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-${geckoview_channel}:${geckoview_version}"
```

With the most recent version pulled from; https://maven.mozilla.org/maven2?prefix=maven2/org/mozilla/geckoview/

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched in the maven find the version you use.  Geckoview has three release channels: Stable, Beta, and Nightly. I strongly recommend you use the Stable not Nightly. it is not statle channel.

you can open the `geckoview` in the link you desc, it show all the version it has. or you can directly open this [geckoview version](https://maven.mozilla.org/?prefix=maven2/org/mozilla/geckoview/geckoview/).

I think you problem is you don not add the maven responsitory in the root project.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.mozilla.org/maven2/"
    }
 }
```

you can try add it to rebuild again

Comment: Aha! So the issue was I added the above line to my application build.gradle instead of my settings.gradle. After changing that it works! Thanks for catching that was likely the root cause. Also, I switched to the non nightly build. So:     `implementation "org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview:95.0.20211129150630"` is working for me  now

Comment: That ^ build is the "stable" build now right?

Comment: Yes, the `:geckoview` build is the stable one.